# Objective C Calling Method Syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, call

I'm a bit confused on how methods are called and the syntax behind it. Can someone dissect two lines of code for me? I've got a bunch of random questions.

```
NSString *testString;  
testString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

So what's going on here? There's a new pointer called testString being created... what does this point to?

Then in the last line, it's being set, but I am quite confused to what. Is:

```
[[NSString alloc] init]
```

returning an address? Is the method "alloc" being called on NSString, and then init being called on that output? What do alloc and init even do?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read **all** of [*Programming With Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1), but specifically [*Objects Are Created Dynamically*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW7)

Answer (score 1):

`alloc`/`init` is the standard way to create new objects in Objective-C. The method `alloc` is a class method of the `NSObject` class, which `NSString` (and most other Objective-C objects) are a subclass of. What it does is allocates memory for the string `testString`, and returns that. The `init` method returns an empty and immutable string. This is equivalent to `[NSString string]`, which returns the exact same thing.

All `NSString *testString` does is declare a new variable, it doesn't allocate any memory or initialize it.

Comment: Are *teststring and teststring two separate things?

Comment: `*testString` is the actual `NSString` object, while `testString` is a pointer to `*testString`.

Comment: So after the first line, both of these are created?

Comment: No, the only thing the first line does is declare a variable. If you tried to get the value of that, it would be undefined. The second line allocates memory and initializes the variable, so it has an actual value and is "created".

Comment: Sorry, I am just confused on how there are two things. When did I create testString? I thought I only created *testString when declaring the variable.

Comment: The two lines can be, and should be, condensed into one (`NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] init];`). Declaring a variable doesn't assign it any value. When you use `alloc`/`init`, you assign that variable an actual value, which is an empty `NSString` object. You created the variable `testString` when you declared it, but you created the actual object in memory when you used `[[NSString alloc] init]`

Comment: That seems contradictory to me - I thought testString was a pointer, not a variable

Comment: It is a pointer to an address in memory, but that pointer is referred to using the variable `testString`.

Comment: I notice you said that "testString is a pointer to *testString" but then you said "that pointer is referred to using the variable testString". Is testString a pointer or a variable?

Answer (score 0):

NSString will alloc a physical memory address, then it will init some methods, you can define your custom method extend init.